# Would you recommend using the Mac OS X Server built-in VPN or Open VPN?

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, openvpn

I'm in a dilemma which VPN solution to choose.

Care to spare your insights on this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any other requirements?  Will any other operating systems need to connect to the VPN.  What OS will be the VPN server?  As it stands now you haven't really provide enough details for anyone to recommend one or the other.

Comment: I thought it was clear from the question it's Mac OS X Server.
In any case, it's the 10.6.2 version.
Both Macs and Windows will connect to it, as well as iPhones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what your client deployments are.

I use both built-in, and OpenVPN on my OS X server, for a few reasons.

1. I use built in so that I can get access to the network with iPhones, and other devices that have pretty simple PPTP or L2TP implementations. There is an OpenVPN toggle for use with a jailbroken iPhone, but its shabby, and only supports routed networks, and not bridged ones.
2. I use OpenVPN for most connections, as I find the compression is better, and it easily supports mDNS traversal across the connection for bonjour browsing and the like. Its very easy to deploy as a virtual machine on the server, and has its own auth server where clients can do one click setup of cert-based auth and configuration.

Short answer - if you have no need for mDNS or bonjour over the connection, or you have a very wide array of devices to support, choose PPTP or L2TP. Otherwise OpenVPN is a great option where the clients can support it.